# Manage Push Notifications from the app

Tags: ios, web-services, apple-push-notifications

This is more a conceptual question. I hope this is the right place to ask.

Let's say I configured my iOS app to receive push notifications. Now I want to present the user some settings with a table view where she/he can enable/disable certain kinds of push notifications.

So for example assume that the user only wants to receive push notifications for comments made by friends not for comments made by all users of the app.

My question is: Do I have to communicate the configuration of the push settings back to the server that creates and pushes the notification in order to avoid even including that particular device or is there some kind of in-app mechanism that allows me to configure the app in a way that it ignores certain kinds of notifications (e.g. identified by a special key).

Would love to get a second opinion on that!

Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to 'communicate' the push settings to your backend to save a lot of overhead. In your scripts you'll only include devices that are configured to receive said notification; this means the front-end (iOS in your case) shows each notification it receives (as it shouldn't receive any the user has opted out of).